# Get R to keep UTF-8 Codepoint representation

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

This question is related to the [utf-8 package for R](https://github.com/patperry/r-utf8). I have a weird problem in which I want emojis in a data set I'm working with to stay in code point representation (i.e. as '\U0001f602'). I want to use the 'FindReplace' function from the [Data Combine package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataCombine/DataCombine.pdf) to turn UTF-8 encodings into prose descriptions of emojis in a [dataset of YouTube comments](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zwmn7vsvo9ihpv/sampletubedata.Rda?dl=0) (using a dictionary I made available [here](https://lyons7.github.io/portfolio/2017-10-04-emoji-dictionary/)). The only issue is that when I 'save' the output as an object in R the nice utf-8 encoding generated by `utf8_encode` for which I can use my dictionary, it disappears...

First I have to adjust the dictionary a bit:

`emojis$YouTube <- tolower(emojis$Codepoint)`

`emojis$YouTube <- gsub("u\\+","\\\\U000", emojis$YouTube)`

Convert to character so as to be able to use utf8_encode:

`emojimovie$test <- as.character(emojimovie$textOriginal)`

This works great, gives output of \U0001f595 (etc.) that can be matched with dictionary entries when it 'prints' in the console.

`utf8_encode(emojimovie$test)`

BUT, when I do this:

`emojimovie$text2 <- utf8_encode(emojimovie$test)`

and then:

`emoemo <- FindReplace(data = emojimovie, Var = "text2", replaceData = emojis, from = "YouTube", to = "Name", exact = TRUE)`

I get all NAs. When I look at the output in $text2 with View I don't see the \U0001f595, I see actual emojis. I think this is why the `FindReplace` function isn't working -- when it gets saved to an object it just gets represented as emojis again and the function can't find any matches. When I try `gsub("\U0001f602", "lolface", emojimovie$text2)`, however, I can actually match and replace things, but I don't want to do this for all ~2,000 or so emojis.... I've tried reading as much as I can about utf-8, but I can't understand why this is happening. I'm stumped! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in the above, you are trying to convert the UTF-8 emoji to a text version. I would recommend going the other direction. Something like

```
emojis <- read.csv('Emoji Dictionary 2.1.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# change U+1F469 U+200D U+1F467 to \U1F469\U200D\U1F467
escapes <- gsub("[[:space:]]*\\U\\+", "\\\\U", emojis$Codepoint)

# convert to UTF-8 using the R parser
codes <- sapply(parse(text = paste0("'", escapes, "'"),
                      keep.source = FALSE), eval)
```

This will convert the text representations like U+1F469 to UTF-8 strings. Then, you can search for these strings in the original data.

**Note:** If you are using Windows, make sure you have the latest release of R; in older versions, the parser gives you the wrong result for strings litke `"\U1F469"`.

The `utf8::utf8_encode` should really only be used if you have UTF-8 and are trying to print it to the screen.

Comment: Yes this works!!! Thank you so much -- ! Never thought about going the other way :P Thanks again!